# Nokogiri: parse and update value in Plist

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, plist

I'm new to Ruby and need to process some plist for a book store, say if I have a plist of books,

```xml
<plist>
<array>
<dict>
  <key>Name</key>
  <string>An Old Man and the Sea</string>
  <key>Available</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
<dict>
  <key>Name</key>
  <string>The Hitchhiker's Guide To Galaxy</string>
  <key>Available</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I need to switch the availability of books, and I have read the plist and parsed the array of books into `books`:

```rb
books.map do |book|
  book.xpath("key/text()") # e.g. ["Name", "Available"]
  book.xpath("string/text()") # e.g. ["An Old Man and the Sea"]
end
```

Questions:

1. How do I read the value `<true/>` and `<false/>`?
2. How do I update the value and save the plist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a gem, there is [plist_lite](https://github.com/tonytonyjan/plist_lite).

```sh
ruby -r plist_lite -e 'p PlistLite.load($stdin.read)' <<EOS
<plist>
<array>
<dict>
  <key>Name</key>
  <string>An Old Man and the Sea</string>
  <key>Available</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
<dict>
  <key>Name</key>
  <string>The Hitchhiker's Guide To Galaxy</string>
  <key>Available</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
EOS
```

output:

```
[{"Name"=>"An Old Man and the Sea", "Available"=>true},
 {"Name"=>"The Hitchhiker's Guide To Galaxy", "Available"=>false}]
```

If you want to do it yourself with `nokogiri`, you can refer to `plist_lite`'s source code here, it also uses `nokogiri`:

https://github.com/tonytonyjan/plist_lite/blob/2de0506/lib/plist_lite.rb#L37-L57

To answer your question:

> How do I read the value `<true/>` and `<false/>`?

```rb
parsed = PlistLite.load(plist_string)
parsed.map{ _1['Available'] }
```

> How do I update the value and save the plist?

```rb
parsed = PlistLite.load(plist_string)
parsed.first['Available']
IO.write 'test.plist', PlistLite.dump(parsed)
```